# Error when connecting to MongoDB Atlas cluster using Node.js driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, server

I'm trying to establish a connection to a MongoDb Atlas cluster from a node.js server.

I get the following message when I run my code:

```
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [splurggen-shard-00-01-nepz5.azure.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to splurggen-shard-00-01-nepz5.azure.mongodb.net:27017 closed
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/Users/________/Projects/Git projects/Splurggen/splurggen_server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:372:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:299:26)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:209:13)
    at net.js:658:12
    at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:479:7) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}]
```

the code:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://____:____@splurggen-nepz5.azure.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect(err => {
    const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
   // perform actions on the collection object
    client.close();
  });
```

I have my IP address listed in the whitelist which seem to be the answer for some but not in my case...

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: That exception is in TLSSocket, maybe this is related to the recent Atlas change to the LetsEncrypt certificates?

Comment: Sorry for late response but I'm using iOS.